# Grok Learning: How to write a Python program to read in a list of integer costs, and print out the total sum of all of the costs

Tags: python, list, input, int, grok

New to Python, doing Introduction to Programming with Python with Grok Learning.
I have this problem where I need to take input, convert to a list, convert to integers and then collect the sum of the integers. Here's what I have so far:

```
expenses = input("Enter the expenses: ")
expenses.split()
for expense in expenses:
  print(int(expenses))
total = sum(expenses)
print("Total: $" + total)
```

I was told I have to loop over the array and then convert to integers. But I have no idea what this means, can someone please show me?

Answer (score 0):

Since you already wrote that `for` loop I'm assuming you know what it means, so you simply need to create another list, for storing the int values:

```
intValues = []
for expense in expenses:
    intValues.append(int(expense))
```

and then `print(sum(intValues))` works the same. You could do the same in just one line using Python's *list comprehension* syntax:

```
intValues = [int(expense) for expense in expenses]
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your error, try this:

```
expenses = input("Enter the expenses (separated by spaces): ")
total = 0
for expense in expenses.split():
  total += int(expense)
  print(expense)
print( "Total: $" + str(total) )
```

A sample session:

```
Enter the expenses (separated by spaces): 12 34 56
12
34
56
Total: $102
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to indent total=sum(expenses) into the for loop and need to save the split result in a variable so modified program is:

```
expenses = input("Enter the expenses: ")
for expense in expenses.split:
  print(int(expense))
  total = sum(expense)
print("Total: $" + total)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
expenses = input('Enter the expenses: ')
expenses = expenses.split()

total = 0
for expense in expenses:
  total += int(expense)

print('Total: $' + str(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

When I did this challenge, this was my code:

```
money = input("Enter the expenses: ")
money = money.split()
total = sum([int(i) for i in money ])
print("Total:", "$" + str(total))
```

The first line is just the input of money. The second line splits each number into a list. The 3rd line calculates the sum of the input as an integer, then the 4th changes it back to a string and prints it.

Answer (score 0):

```
print("Total: $"+str(sum([int(i) for i in input("Enter the expenses: ").split()])))
```

I tried to make it in one line :)

Comment: "I tried to make it in one line"—why? Readability counts.